# query to fetch data from multiple tables in one API (SpringBOOT + JPA)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, hql, jql

The below is the ERD of my DB schema.

[image]

I need to get all movies with different params passed in the API.

1. Need to get movies data where language is (english and hindi, genres is action and fantasy

Entities:

**categorystudio**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categorystudio")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class CategoryOfStudio implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CategoryOfStudio() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="categorystudio_id")
    private Long categorystudio_id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "categorystudio_title")
    private String categorystudio_title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "categorystudio", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Title> categorystudio = new HashSet<>();
```

**title**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "title")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Title implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "title_id")
    private Long title_id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "title_name")
    private String title_name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    @JoinTable(name = "title_genre",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "genresCategory_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "title_id") })
    private Set<GenresCategory> genre_title = new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    @JoinTable(name = "title_language",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "language_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "title_id") })
    private Set<Language> title_language = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="title_categorystudio_id")
    private CategoryOfStudio categorystudio;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "movieTitle")
    private Movie movie;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "tvShowTitle")
    private TvShow tvShowTitle;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "kidTitle")
    private Kid kidTitle;

    public Title() {
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "comicMaindata", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<ComicData> comicMaindata = new HashSet<>();

}
```

language

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "language")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class Language implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Language() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="language_id")
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "language_name")
        private String languageName;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "comicDataLanguage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<ComicDetailedData> comicDataLanguage = new HashSet<>();

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "title_language")
        private Set<Title> title_language = new HashSet<>();

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "comicTitleLanguage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<ComicData> comicTitleLanguage = new HashSet<>();

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "comicMainLanguage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<ComicData> comicMainLanguage = new HashSet<>();
```

**genresCategory**

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "genresCategory")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class GenresCategory implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public GenresCategory() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="genresCategory_id")
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "genresCategory_name")
        private String name;



        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "genre_title")
        private Set<Title> genre_title = new HashSet<>();
```

**Controller**:

```
  @GetMapping("/categoryByName/{name}")
@Timed
public Title getAllComicsByName(@RequestParam List<String> genres,
                                @RequestParam List<String> languages){
    return titlesRepository.findByStudiosGenresLanguages(genres, languages);
}
```

**Respository**

```
@Repository
public interface TitleRepository extends JpaRepository<Title, Long> {

        @Query("SELECT T FROM TITLE T WHERE T.LANGUAGE.NAME IN (:languages) AND T.GENRE.NAME IN (:genres)")
Title findByStudiosGenresLanguages(@Param("genres") List<String> genres, @Param("languages") List<String> languages);


}
```

**Error:**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'titlesRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'titleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.comicflix.library.domain.Title com.comicflix.library.repository.TitleRepository.findByStudiosGenresLanguages(java.util.List,java.util.List)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at com.comicflix.library.ComicFlixLibraryApp.main(ComicFlixLibraryApp.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'titleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.comicflix.library.domain.Title com.comicflix.library.repository.TitleRepository.findByStudiosGenresLanguages(java.util.List,java.util.List)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.comicflix.library.domain.Title com.comicflix.library.repository.TitleRepository.findByStudiosGenresLanguages(java.util.List,java.util.List)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TITLE is not mapped [SELECT T FROM TITLE T WHERE T.LANGUAGE.NAME IN (:languages) AND T.GENRE.NAME IN (:genres)]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TITLE is not mapped [SELECT T FROM TITLE T WHERE T.LANGUAGE.NAME IN (:languages) AND T.GENRE.NAME IN (:genres)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TITLE is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    ... 75 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please let me know how can i get response in such according to the inputs passed to the API.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: please paste full error output here

Comment: @luboskrnac updated question with more part of error report

Comment: Please also paste here your JPA entities. It says that validation of that query failed. Are you sure that error stack doesn't contain more info about this validation failure

Comment: Updated in question .. i am stuck whether it's a query error or any other error

Comment: The error is on method: findByStudiosCategoriesGenresLanguages but you've posted findByGenresLanguages can you please post the method with the failure?

Comment: Updated everything now @SimonMartinelli ..Please check

Answer (score 0):

So far we don't have enough info to help you. But suspicious is usage of uppercase entity/field names. These should correspond with Java naming.

EDIT:
After updating your question is clear that your JPQL naming doesn't correspond with Java naming + incorrect join as @Simon Martinelli pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

JPQL is not SQL! JPQL is operating on the Entity model and the names must be in the same case.

Additionally if you want to query for ToMany relationships you must join these.

This query should work (I haven't tested it):

```
 @Query("SELECT t FROM Titel t join t.title_language l join t.genre_title g where l.name IN (:languages) AND g.name IN (:genres)")
```

Comment: Will try this and let you know

Comment: At the time I created answer, there wasn't enough info concretely fix the query. Your answer definitely help, but it would be fair to mention that there already is answer which found general problem. You are just narrowing the solution further.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract com.comicflix.library.domain.Title com.comicflix.library.repository.TitleRepository.findByStudiosGenresLanguages(java.util.List,java.util.List) but parameter 'Optional[genres]' not found in annotated query 'select t from Title t join t.title_language l where l.name IN (:languages)'!

Comment: The query you post has no generes parameter and looks like: select t from Title t join t.title_language l where l.name IN (:languages)'!